# PostgreSQL server upgrade from 9.x to 10 easiest way

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have been trying to upgrade my postgres server from 9.6 to 10 using pg_upgrade. However, getting stuck at Consistency checks for the required libraries.
The loadable_libraried.txt reads:

```
could not load library "$libdir/postgis_topology-2.3": 
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis_topology-2.3": No such file or directory
```

I'm trying this out for the first time. Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: PostGIS is a separate library from PostgreSQL, an add-on so to speak. I'm not sure what strategy you want to use to solve your problem, but you might want to look at either installing PostGIS, or removing the dependencies from your upgrade. I can't advise either way here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you have installed PostGis on your PostgreSQL 9.6 installation, you need to add it to your PostgreSQL 10 installation as well.
Download it if you don't have it and install it:

```
wget https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.3.7.tar.gz
tar zxf postgis-2.3.7.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.3.7
./configure --with-pgconfig=/PATH_TO_POSTGRESQL_10_pg_config
make
make install
```

And then continue with the pg_upgrade.
( You might need to repeat the procedure with other extensions ).